# Good practice SI units align environment - tufte-book class

Tags: align, tufte, units

In a mission to purify my LaTeX-coding I encountered some problems.

First problem after changing from book-class to tufte-book class I had to set all numbers in math-mode, meaning the units become italic. So I adapted the numbers in the text. 
As you see I'm using the align environment for my equations and I have to type \unit{} before every SI unit. As I have 3 courses of about 250 pages each to purify I start asking my self if this was really the correct way to do.

1) So is the tufte-book class the way to go for course of 250 pages maths and physics?
2) Is this align environment the correct way to work with SI-units

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,a4paper]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,units} 
\begin{document}
\section{Toegepast}
Een werfkraan verplaatst een pallet bakstenen met een massa van $100\,\unit{kg}$ $13,5\,\unit{m}$ naar boven. De kraan verricht hier een arbeid. Gaan we er van uit dat de kraan de stenen opheft met een constante kracht die even groot is als de zwaartekracht op die pallet stenen dan kunnen we dit als volgt berekenen:
\begin{description}
\item Gegeven:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item $m=100\,\unit{kg}$
    \item $\Delta x=13,5\,\unit{m}$
    \end{itemize}
\item Gevraagd: $W=?$
\item Oplossing:
    \begin{align*}
    W&=F \cdot \Delta x\\
    W&=m \cdot g \cdot \Delta x\\
    W&=100\,\unit{kg} \cdot 9,81 \dfrac{\unit{N}}{\unit{kg}} \cdot 13,5\,\unit{m}\\
    W&=13\,243,5\,\unit{Nm}\\
    W&=13,2 \cdot 10^3\,\unit{J}
    \end{align*}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: erhm, the `siunitx` package of course

Comment: Yes, please start using [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), the `units` version on CTAN dates back to 1998 (!), while `siunitx` is actively maintained.

Comment: I've read the documentation, and will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointed in the comments, `siunitx` package should be used. Your code should become:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,a4paper]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,units} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\section{Toegepast}
Een werfkraan verplaatst een pallet bakstenen met een massa van $100\,\si{kg}$ $13,5\,\si{m}$ naar boven. De kraan verricht hier een arbeid. Gaan we er van uit dat de kraan de stenen opheft met een constante kracht die even groot is als de zwaartekracht op die pallet stenen dan kunnen we dit als volgt berekenen:
\begin{description}
\item Gegeven:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item $m=100\,\si{kg}$
    \item $\Delta x=13,5\,\si{m}$
    \end{itemize}
\item Gevraagd: $W=?$
\item Oplossing:
    \begin{align*}
    W&=F \cdot \Delta x\\
    W&=m \cdot g \cdot \Delta x\\
    W&=100\,\si{kg} \cdot 9,81 \si{N.kg} \cdot 13,5\,\si{m}\\
    W&=13\,243,5\,\si{Nm}\\
    W&=13,2 \cdot 10^3\,\si{J}
    \end{align*}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]